# Remove or Consume pop up coming after sending SMS

Tags: android

I have an android app which needs to keep  sending SMS. My problem is that whenever we send a message we get a pop up showing (your SMS charges and your curent talktime balance in  phone). When i send many SMS these pop ups keep getting accumulated one over the other which is undesirable for me. I need a way out to either remove or somehow consume these pop ups.
Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

a pop up? Do you mean a toast? or notifications accumulating below the status bar?

You'll have to pardon my seemingly simple question. In the US, I've had multiple Android phones on at least two carriers, and I don't get any such message in any form, but may be that's because I've always had unlimited texting so additional texts do not cost me anything.

I bet you're talking about notifications accumulating in the status bar. So if your carrier is doing that, take a look at the code in the "API Demos" > App > Notification > Status Bar

There in the callback attached to the "Clear Notification" button, you'll find the code you're looking for.

And if I could suggest something, I know that many notifications accumulating on top of each other can be super annoying, but if you can try to consolidate all those notifications into one notification at least with the running count (unless your user explicitly opts out from being notified). This way, you still communicate to the user the most important part of the information - how many texts in total his phone has been sending so far, without completely overwhelming him with many-many notifications about basically the same event happening over and over again.

For those who don't know, "API Demos" is a free application you can download from the Market. And there may be several to choose from, so just pick the one with five stars next to it, but "API Demos" is also the same sample code that comes with different SDKs when you download it with the SDK Manager, and you can access that code when you create a new Android Project with the New Android Project... wizard from within Eclipse and then select the radio button "Create Existing Project from Sample" (or something like that, I don't have Eclipse in front of me, so the wording may be slightly incorrect). And of course, if you don't use Eclipse, you can always find that sample code through the Sample code directory itself.

As a potentially more elegant alternative, or may be just in case your carrier is indeed crude enough to pop up an actual modal dialog every time a text is sent, it may be that your carrier is using a broadcast receiver to trigger those notifications or those dialogs, so if that's the case, and hopefully the carrier isn't using "100" as a priority for its receiver, it may be possible for you to register a receiver with "100", and then kill the broadcast before it propagates to the other receivers. But of course, that's assuming that your carrier designed it that way for you.

Comment: no i'm not talking about the notifications in status bar. Rather i'm talking about a dialog box with "OK" button showing me my current talktime balance and SMS amount charged for that SMS.

Comment: Ah ok, have you tried intercepting the SMS Broadcasted intent? It may or may not be possible, depending on the priority they've selected for themselves.

Comment: I tried intercepting the SMS broadcast intent with broadcast receiver priority=1000 , but still the pop up is not intercepted by my broadcast receiver. I think these pop ups aren't messages they are something else. That's why broadcast receiver is not able to intercept them.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The only remaining option would be to contact the Carrier in question and file a usability bug with them. Their UI design is atrocious and could be done a hell of a lot better, while still informing their customers of their balance. I'm sorry that I can't be of any more help.

Comment: This kind of messages maybe initiated by Carrier. But I don't think you can remove such messages by contacting them.